# How to pass an array of strings to a function?

Tags: c

Could anybody please tell me why is the output of both the prints are not same? How to pass an array of strings to a function then?

```
main()
{
    char b[10][10];
    printf("%p, %p, %p\n", b, b[0], b[9]);
    getStrListFromString(b);
}

void getStrListFromString(char **strList)
{
    printf("%p, %p, %p\n", strList, strList[0], strList[9]);
}
```

Expected OUTPUT :

```
0x7fffbe4ecf00, 0x7fffbe4ecf00, 0x7fffbe4ecf5a
0x7fffbe4ecf00, 0x7fffbe4ecf00, 0x7fffbe4ecf5a
```

Actual Output :

```
0x7fffbe4ecf00, 0x7fffbe4ecf00, 0x7fffbe4ecf5a
0x7fffbe4ecf00, 0x7fffbe4ecf80, (nil)
```

Comment: that's not the way to pass 2d array

Comment: try `void getStrListFromString(char strList[10][10])` for the prototype. 2D arrays are not pointers on 1D arrays.

Comment: Also, pointers printed using `%p` must be cast to `void *`.

Comment: Stop wasting your time and enable compiler warnings/errors. This code has 3-4 of them that shouldn't be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function expects a `char **` but you're passing it a `char [10][10]`.  These are not the same.

An array when passed to a function decayed to a pointer to the first element.  So when you pass a `char [10][10]` (an array of size 10 of `char [10]`) to a function it decays into a `char (*)[10]` (a pointer to a `char [10]`.

Change your function to accept either `char [10][10]` or `char (*)[10]`.

Comment: I understood. But couldn't understand why I am getting `b[0]` as `0x7fffbe4ecf00` in main but `strList[0]` as `0x7fffbe4ecf80` in the function.

Comment: @Karthik [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  When you pass an incompatible pointer to a function, you can't accurately predict what will happen.

Comment: but there is certainly a predictable pattern. I always get (address + 128 bytes)?

Comment: @Karthik You can't depend on that behavior.  For example, when I run this code I get address + 70.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the core issue about pointer-to-pointer having absolutely nothing to do with multi-dimensional arrays, your also has various other bugs:

```
main() // obsolete form of main(), won't compile unless C90
{
    char b[10][10]; // uninitialized
    printf("%p, %p, %p\n", b, b[0], b[9]); // should be void pointers
    getStrListFromString(b); // wrong type of parameter
    // return statement necessary here in C90
}

void getStrListFromString(char **strList) // should not be pointer-to-pointer
{
    printf("%p, %p, %p\n", strList, strList[0], strList[9]); // same issue as in main
}
```

The fact that this code compiled means that your compiler is either complete crap or incorrectly configured. You need to fix that asap.

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getStrListFromString(char strList[10][10])
{
    printf("%p, %p, %p\n", (void*)strList, (void*)strList[0], (void*)strList[9]);
}

int main (void)
{
    char b[10][10];
    printf("%p, %p, %p\n", (void*)b, (void*)b[0], (void*)b[9]);
    getStrListFromString(b);
}
```